# Error in ignite context creation

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

Hi i have just started exploring Apache-Ignite and facing a error initially in ignite context creation--

```
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
val ic = new IgniteContext[Integer, Integer](sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
#Error:
 <console>:30: error: org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext does not take type parameters
   val ic = new IgniteContext[Integer, Integer](sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
```

But every where on internet this line works(as it shows in examples provided).

Versions- apache-ignite-1.8.0-src,  spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7

And I am starting the shell by

```
./bin/spark-shell  --packages org.apache.ignite:ignite-spark:1.7.0, org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:1.8.0 --master local  --repositories http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite
```

Can somebody help me with this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type arguments was removed in Ignite 1.7 according to that [task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2929).

Just change to
`val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())`

Comment: @Mitya-Thanks for the info...do you have any link where i can get a complete sample program flow ,,starting from loading to ignite cache to read from cache.

Comment: Check this out [IgniteContext & IgniteRDD](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd)

Comment: Followed that, but as i can't give type parameter in ignitecontext creation...then where should i give type parameter.because after val cacheRdd = ic.fromCache("partitioned") when I tried cacheRdd.savePairs(sc.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (i, i))) #Error: found   : i.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: Nothing
              cacheRdd.savePairs(sc.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (i, i)))

Comment: Probably documentation is outdated, set types explicitly: val cacheRdd = igniteContext.fromCache[Int, Int]("partitioned");

        cacheRdd.savePairs(sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (i, i)))

Comment: Did that,,,and able to apply filter also by val result = cache.filter(_._2 < 15).collect()... But how to run sql query over that. val result = cache.sql("select * from Row").collect()  #Error: javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: partitioned. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable.

Comment: Because you have to define types for querying, refer to [documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes) for details.